# Distorted svg icon marker in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, svg

I'm using the Maps API v3 in a web site I'm developing, but my icons get distorted in mobile devices. I'm using this code:

```
var icon = {
    url: 'http://wikimaki.augustocarmo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/pin.svg',
    size: new google.maps.Size( sizeX, sizeY ),
    origin: new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point( sizeX/2, sizeY ),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size( sizeX, sizeY )
};

var lojaTemp = new google.maps.Marker({ 

    position: position,
    icon: icon,
    map: map,
    title: title,
});
```

You can check out here: http://wikimaki.augustocarmo.com.br/lojas

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, what mobile device gives you trouble? I looked at the link using my android device, and the icons looked the same as when i use chrome on my desktop.

Comment: Also tested on window's phone with mobile IE, and the icon seemed perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm testing in iOS 8, both Chrome and Safari squeeze the icon... print screen: http://bit.ly/1E5Yv3q

Comment: Maybe the dimensions in the SVG file are overriding it somehow? Also try `optimized: true` in your Marker class.

Comment: When I use `optimized: true` the incons wont show in the mobile browsers